# Python - Searching for text, copying part of the line

Tags: python, search

SO I have a text file (alarm.txt) that I convert to a string. The alarm.txt file contains:

```
Customer Name: LOU
Site: Sao Paulo
Node Name: SPRouter
IP address: 1.2.3.4
```

I open it using read(). I have experimented with readlines() but that doesn't seem to work as well:

```
alarm = open('alarm.txt').read()
```

So now I am trying to search for "Site:" and copy the text after Site: until the end of the line (in this example i would want to copy "Sao Paulo" into a new string).

I have experimented with re.findall, re.match, re.search.

```
print re.search(r"Site:*\n", alarm)
```

I hoped the code above would search for Site: in the string and print the line "Site: Sao Paulo" but it errors. Then copying what comes after Site: into a seperate string, is another story.

Comment: could you tell us what error is thrown please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
print re.search(r"Site:\s*(.*)", alarm).group(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to offer a different solution, you can split the lines into key/value pairs and populate a dict:

```
conf = dict()
for line in open("test.txt"):
    key, value = line.rstrip().split(": ", 1)
    conf[key] = value

print conf["Site"]
```

Comment: +1.  Or this one liner: `conf = dict(line.rstrip().split(": ", 1) for line in open("test.txt"))`

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions have a special syntax. To be short, you are looking for

```
re.findall(r"^Site:\s*(.*)$", alarm, re.MULTILINE)
```

But you can do as well

```
m = re.search(r"^Site:\s*(.*)$", alarm, re.MULTILINE)
```

and then continue with e.g. `m.group(1)`.

Why this all?

- `r""` turns a string into a raw string, so that all `\` are preserved and given to the `re` engine.
- The RE itself: `^` is start of string or line, `\s*` is an optional sequence of whitespace (blank, tab etc.), `()` is a capture group, `.*` is "everything" and `$` is end of line or string.
- `re.MULTILINE` is for recognizing lines in the string.
- `m.group` gives you the `()` groups.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Now, how would we convert the output to a string and clean off the \r? It outputs this: ['Sao Paulo\r'] . I want to take Sao Paulo and put it into a web form.

Comment: You could post-process your results, e.g. by `[s.strip() for s in your_result]` - or you could pre-process your data with `alarm = open('alarm.txt').read().replace("\r\n", "\n")`.